# Node js get value field type with form enctype multiform

Tags: node.js, forms

I am using following code:

**node.js**

```
app.post('/upload_file', function(req, res) {
    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    var image_name=req.body.image_name;

    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        var file_name=randomstring.generate(7)+"_"+filename;
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/uploads/' + file_name);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
           // res.send('uploaded Successfully');

        });

    });
    res.send(image_name+""+file_name);
});
```

**Html**

```
<form action="/upload_file" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select an image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="image"> 
  <input type="text" value="test" name="image_name">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

File is uploaded successfully but I am not able to extract field `image_name`,
it gives `undefined` in output.

Comment: Get the file name from `req.files.file.name`?

Comment: I want image_name value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like node doesn't parse multipart/form-data by default, hence your field image_name is undefined.

Good that you are using busboy but the only way to capture image_name which is your file type input is by using:

```
req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        if(fieldname === 'image_name') {
             image_name = fieldname;
         }
});
```

For fieldname, you may need something like this:

```
req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated, encoding, mimetype) {
      if(fieldname === 'image_name') {
                 image_name = fieldname;
             }
    });
```

Comment: Above code is not working for me.
Its not going in if_condtition.

Comment: Added the second part to retrieve fieldname, may be this will help.

Answer (score 0):

After Various experiment i got following solution

```
req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log('Field [' + fieldname + ']: value: ' + inspect(val));
      });
```